# Drag items placed on UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I have the code below, and need to drag the views so they can be repositioned. However, on drag, the view simply disappears. How can I make the views draggable while on top of the stack view?

Stack View:

```
let sView = UIStackView()
    sView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.Vertical
    sView.distribution = .FillEqually
    sView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.Center
    sView.spacing = 15
    sView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    sView.addArrangedSubview(view1)
    sView.addArrangedSubview(view2)
    sView.addArrangedSubview(view3)
    sView.layoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
    sView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(sView)
    sView.centerXAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.centerXAnchor).active = true
    sView.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.centerYAnchor).active = true
```

The views; `view1`, `view2`, and `view3` have similar code as below:

```
let view1 = UIView()
    view1.frame = CGRectMake(30, 50, 50, 80)
    view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    view1.layer.cornerRadius = 6
    let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("draggedView:"))
    view1.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    view1.userInteractionEnabled = true
    view1.tag = 1
    view1.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(85).active = true
    view1.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(55).active = true
```

The `draggedView` function:

```
func draggedView(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer){ 
    let loc = gesture.locationInView(self.view)
    let gesturedView = gesture.view
    gesturedView!.center = loc
}
```

Comment: Hi, do you have a simpler answer to the question?

Comment: The answer given below works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brian,

This code does what I think your looking to do. Obviously you need to go thru it carefully and change variable names, but I sure you up to it!

```
func draggedView(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began) {
        self.source = editorSVB!.arrangedSubviews.indexOf(sender.view!)! as Int
    }
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed) {
        center = sender.view?.center
        let translation = sender.translationInView(sender.view)
        center = CGPointMake(center!.x + translation.x, center!.y + translation.y)
        sender.view?.center = center!
        sender .setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: sender.view)
    }
     for blah in self.editorSVB!.arrangedSubviews {
        let no = blah.frame.intersect((sender.view?.frame)!)
        if (!no.origin.x.isInfinite) {
             self.object = editorSVB!.arrangedSubviews.indexOf(blah)! as Int
             if (self.object != self.source) {
                print("self,object, self.object",self,object, self.source)
                self.executable = self.object
            }
        }
    }
}
```